# Javascript equivalent of @SuppressWarnings?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I am currently running Sonar for the static analysis of my code. When I was analyzing java files and wanted to suppress a certain warning, I used the @SuppressWarnings(nameOfTheWarningOnSonar) annotation. I wanted to know if there was a simple equivalent in Javascript to suppress specific warnings on Sonar.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the easiest way is for sure :

**Correct what Sonar is saying** :)

but let's assume that it's false positive.

Here are the list of possible method to fix this issue :

**Since November 2014 :** *tag support*

```
// NOSONAR
the code who display Sonar error
```

is now fully supported by the JavaScript check (thanks @[RPallas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320113/rpallas))

**When you don't control the Sonar :** *quite ugly method*

```
try {

  the code who display Sonar error     

} catch(err) { }
```

If you catch any possible problem, Sonar can't detect something (thanks @[JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5091166/javascript)).

But the best way is for sure to modify the configuration of Sonar :

**When you control Sonar :** *add a plugin*

To use the CheckStyle plugin on Sonar : (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)

The solution will be to add a Checkstyle structured comment to the offending class to suppress a particular check.

The suppression comment (SuppressionCommentFilter) format required is like this:

```
//CHECKSTYLE:OFF

     the code who display Sonar error    

//CHECKSTYLE:ON
```

But I send you to the documentation of this plugin (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html)

I hope this answer helps.

Comment: 'correct what Sonar is saying' is off topic, and try/catch is a wrong answer.

The direct simple answer below is just better.

Answer (score 6):

You can put // NOSONAR on the line triggering the warning.

Comment: It's indeed possible since someone fix this issue in November 2014 *http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-293*

I was not aware of it and it was not supported before :) thanks :)

Comment: That’s not equivalent because it suppresses **all** warnings on that line, not just the one warning class one wants to ignore.